# Youtube-like player and list by bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to make two column and left column has many items
and it is scrollable, right column should keep still.

Like left-right reverse of youtube.

How can I make this with bootstrap??

Using col system is right approach??

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    my items
    my items
    .
    .
  </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
   not scrollable and fixed in the middle
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for this. If you want to stick with Bootstrap then use [Bootstrap flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

Comment: THank you for your suggestion. I learned `Flexbox` and it fulfills my request.